# How to save story progress?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I did save story progress with Franklin's phone, but it keeps restarting everything when I get quit the game.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, but here is how you can try to fix this problem:

1. Thanks to our fellow member Elena for this one ([How do I turn autosave on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156929/how-do-i-turn-autosave-on))

> "Its on the Settings tab, actually. (for me at least)
>   Pause>Settings>Saving>Autosave
>
> In PC: Pause>Settings>Saving And Startup>Autosave"

2. Thanks to our fellow member Dom for this one ([How can I save my progress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131571/how-can-i-save-my-progress))
   [image]

NOTE: Only works when not in mission.

Text about the autosave which may help:

> The auto save feature is pretty neat, as it'll save after every
>   completed mission, mission replay, random encounter, activity, in
>   short: anything of relevance. The auto save feature won't save after
>   you improve a skill, however, and if you're in flight school or in the
>   shooting range, you'll have to leave those before the auto save
>   feature does its job.
>
> However, the quicksave feature (accessible from the cellphone) is
>   pretty neat too. Try it out, and you'll never want to go back to your
>   safehouse to save, never. Well, maybe you'll occasionally want to
>   return to change clothes, watch TV, fetch whatever vehicle is in your
>   safehouse garage, or to time travel 6 ingame hours into the future.
>   The beauty about the quicksave feature, is that it'll save your
>   current position, the vehicle you're currently driving (but not its
>   damage, which is kinda nice) and is just perfect to abuse the stock
>   market. Just quicksave in front of the assassination missions, start
>   the mission, jolt down the stock you'll want to invest in, load the
>   previous quicksave, then invest in those stocks as everyone (as you
>   won't be able to switch while on assassination mission).
>
> Basically, auto save does a good job, but quicksave does an awesome
>   one. Use it well and do it often.
>   From our fellow user Nolonar ([Do I need to save my game manually?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131587/do-i-need-to-save-my-game-manually))

Hope this works :)